# PL/SQL While Loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am a beginner in PL/SQL. I want to run simple WHILE LOOP and I am receiving errors.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
  counter INTEGER := 01;
BEGIN
  WHILE counter <= 30 
  LOOP
    SELECT name, count(iid) as Counts
    FROM table.orders
    WHERE date_inserted >= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.00.00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
    AND date_inserted <= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.'counter'.00 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
    HAVING count(iid) >= 60
    ORDER BY count(iid) DESC;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I am getting these errors when running the code:

```
*Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
  counter INTEGER := 01;
BEGIN
  WHILE counter <= 30 
  LOOP
    SELECT iname, count(iid) as Counts
    FROM table.orders
    WHERE date_inserted >= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.00.00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
    AND date_inserted <= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.'counter'.00 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
    HAVING count(iid) >= 60
    ORDER BY count(iid) DESC;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 9, column 49:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   Action:

What seems to be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you reformat your question so that it appears as fixed text by indenting it?  It's hard to read in paragraph form.

Comment: `TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.' + counter + '.00 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')`

Comment: Wait, I will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: artm - will this work also...  TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.'||TO_CHAR(counter)|| + '.00 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')

Comment: I never initialize my variables in oracle above the first BEGIN line.  I do not know why I do that however.

Comment: Your query is missing an `INTO` and a `GROUP BY`. Once you've fixed the syntax error you will have to resolve these.

Comment: I'm guessing the next question will be "where is my output?"

Answer (score 1):

Don't concatenate, it would be more efficient (and in my opinion easier to read) if you simply add the counter to a proper date value. You also don't increment the counter and you are missing the `group by` in the query. And finally, the result of a query must be stored somewhere.

```
DECLARE
  counter INTEGER := 1;
  l_from_date DATE;
  l_name varchar(200);
  l_count integer;
BEGIN
  from_date := TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.00.00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM');

  WHILE counter <= 30 
  LOOP
    SELECT name, count(iid) as Counts
       into l_name, l_count --<< store the result somewhere
    FROM table.orders 
    WHERE date_inserted >= l_from_date 
    AND date_inserted <= l_from_date + counter
    GROUP BY name --<< this was missing as well
    HAVING count(iid) >= 60
    ORDER BY count(iid) DESC;

    counter := counter + 1;  --<< increment the counter

    -- do something with l_name and l_count ....
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

---

Unrelated to this question: but you should avoid NLS specific format strings for date values. Better use a format that doesn't depend on the language used by the SQL client (or application) running the code. e.g. `to_date('2016-09-14 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: Good advice, but `date '2016-09-14` is a lot less bother.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: I know and I prefer the ANSI literals myself - I just don't wanted to introduce yet another "new" thing (seeing that the OP is clearly a newcomer)

Comment: Sorry but `AND date_inserted <= l_from_date + counter` would add a whole day. I think what the OP really wants is `AND date_inserted <= l_from_date + counter/1440` (1440 being the number of minutes in a day).

Comment: @archimede: No idea. But I'd prefer using `l_from_date + interval '1' minute * counter` in that case (to make intentions clear)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use CONCAT or || after converting counter to char in order to add it in between those strings.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I don't see you increment the counter. Is it by design??

To answer your question, as mentioned in comments, you would want to use `concat` for concatenating the string. Change your where condition to

```
WHERE date_inserted >= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.00.00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
AND date_inserted <= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.'||to_char(counter)||'.00 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
```

In fact in Oracle 11 or newer versions (may be previous too but I never worked on those), you don't need to do conversions explicitly. So you can directly concatenate `counter` to the string.

```
WHERE date_inserted >= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.00.00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
AND date_inserted <= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.'||counter||'.00 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
```

Comment: Oracle has supported implicit conversions since many versions ago.

Comment: Oracle has always supported implicit conversions, as have all mainstream SQL vendors.

Comment: that's why I explicitly mentioned `(may be previous too but I never worked on those)`. Thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the strings directly

```
WHERE date_inserted >= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.00.00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
AND date_inserted <= TO_DATE('14-SEP-16 12.'||counter||'.00 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')
```